# How to delete a column of a table and shift the rest to the left without affecting the previous tables in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that contains table of data with fixed column E to S and unfixed rows. Every week i copy this table into another workbook called 'Summary'. I need to do some calculation for the table but first i need to delete data on column P and shift the rest to the left. However, i only want to delete column P of the currents week and ignore the weeks before. This is because i already deleted column P for previous weeks. I am currently doing it manually. since i have 20 table of data per week, it is time consuming as i need to automate most of the process. . I've create the code for the calculation process needed after deleting column P. How do i find the last table of data pasted on the worksheet and then delete column P without affecting the previous data?

This is the calculation code that i used. Probably i need to create a code for deleting column P and shift the others to left before running this calculation code.

```
Dim ws As WorksheetDim y As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer, r As Long, j As Long


Set y = ThisWorkbook


For Each ws In y.Worksheets
    For Each rng In ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3).Areas
        If rng.Rows.Count > 1 And rng.Columns.Count = 14 Then
            j = 2
            r = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, 1).Row + 1
            ws.Cells(r, rng.Columns(1).Column).Value = "total expenses"
            For i = rng.Columns(2).Column To rng.Columns(2).Column + 12
                    ws.Cells(r, i).Formula = "=SUM(" & rng.Columns(j).Address & ")"
                    j = j + 1
            Next i
       End If
    Next rng
Next
```

This is the example of the table after i paste to the worksheet where i need to delete column P (99-0) for the current week table.
[Example of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt5Ac.png)

Comment: That's not very clear. How is the week determined? For how many rows you want to delete column P?

Comment: I've edited the question. Based on the example, i have two tables, the above table is last week data whereas the below table is the current data. I need to delete the whole column P and shift the rest to left so that it will be the same size as the previous week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your data layout, you need first to capture column `S` and then move to column P accordingly. This should do it:

```
With ws
  .Range(.Range("S1").End(xlDown), .Range("S999999").End(xlUp)).Offset(,-3).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End With
```

Comment: To use this command, do i need to declare the table range every time?

Comment: @mmaz you can do this to delete column P `for Each ws` before you proceed with your calculation. I dont see any variables needed apart the `ws` for this operation.

Comment: i did try on the code, it doesnt result in error but still all the columns are there, not even one got deleted

Comment: @mmaz did you try it on the layout of your example? As I said I assumed that only the new week has data in column S, everything else in this column being blank (no data, no formulas), so we find this data and we move 3 columns to the left to delete the corresponding column P data. Anyway, it wont work if these asumptions are not correct.

Comment: Hi, @A.S.H, finally its working very well. thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: @mmaz you are welcome. glad to know that the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just delete column P first before you paste?  Without the sample data, it's hard to tell what your asking.

```
Columns("P:P").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: Hi @DavidPedack, i tried to used the suggestion and modify it but seems that its not working. iI tried with this,
For Each ws In xy.Worksheets
For Each rng In ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3).Areas
        If rng.Rows.Count > 1 And rng.Columns.Count = 15 Then
        Columns("P:P").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
        
    Next rng
Next

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the column by its index in the range.

```
Range.CurrentRegion.Columns(12).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

The range above is where you pasted your table. 12 is the column index. In range E:S column P is 12.

Comment: this is my snippet code where x is the source workbook and y is the destination workbook.
x.Worksheets("Air").Range("A14").CurrentRegion.Copy
y.Worksheets("Aired").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
y.Worksheets("Aired").Range.CurrentRegion.Columns(12).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
However, error occured. Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment